# Printing in while loop, clearing previous iteration prints

Tags: validation, input, while-loop, python-3.5

I have the following code:

```
 print("Hi there!")
 def inputyournumber():
     while True:
          num = input("your number is?:")
          if int(num) <100:
               break
     return
```

The output is:

```
 Hi there!
 your number is?: 101
 your number is?: 1002
 your number is?: 100
 your number is?: 99
```

i just want the initial prints: and the final output until a correct input is entered:

```
Hi there!
your number is?: 99
```

Erasing the initially wrong inputs, but keeping the prints prior the loop. Is it possible? Or do i have to reprint them? My issue in just clearing everything then reprint the prior texts together with the correct input is that it may consume more time for more complex part of the code with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean it only print out the number you entered when the number you enter is 100?

First, the input you get, will be a string, so the comparison won't work.

maybe this is what you wanted?

```
def printnum():
    while True:
        print('Hi there!')
        num = input("your number is: ")
        if num != '100':
            continue
        break
    print(num)
printnum()
```

Comment: agree, the comparison wont work my initial way. I wanted to remove all times when the entered value is not less than 100(kindly see edited version), while keeping the messages printed prior to the function `inputyournumber()`